# Data from rows aggregated by ID with results transposed in r

Tags: arrays, r, concatenation

I have environmental data that is arranged into rows for every parameter and I would like to have a single row per sampling event in order to analyze it.

It looks like (with actually ~20 parameter types and a almost a million rows)

```
ID  Location Parameter  Result
a1  x1       DO         7.3      
a1  x1       pH         8.1 
a1  x1       Salinity   32.7 
b2  x2       DO         7.6      
b2  x2       pH         8.3 
b2  x2       Salinity   31.2
```

I would like it to look like

```
ID   Location  DO   pH    Salinity
a1   x1        7.3  8.1   32.7      
b2   x2        7.6  8.3   31.2
```

However, certain parameters were measured within each site visit at different depths as well. I am toying with how to deal with this aspect of the data conceptually, but obviously it is hard to get a sense of what is important to analyze without being able to visualize it well. There are continuous depth measurements (eg. 0.112, 0.527, 1.244, 5.891 representing the meters down it was collected) and a depth code I could sort by (eg. Surface, Half Meter, Meter, Bottom). I think just accepting the codes will be fine, especially since the bottom depth is actually it's own row as a parameter and that is the only one that should really change much.

I see my options as to either 1) accept that some data will not be in the same row and (I believe) unavailable to analyze together in ArcGIS which is my end goal program for much of this data once cleaned (different parameter types only measured at certain depths). If I do this I might just add the bottom code to the unique ID which is currently a text string of site plus date. or 2) somehow code the new columns with perhaps the depth code being combined with the parameter names. So for location a1 sampling event xxxx I would have a row that had results for perhaps salinityS, salinityM, salinityB, pHS, pHM, pHB, and DO. Hopefully I'm conceptualizing that clearly, but suggestions are very welcome.

Also, there is a time stamp for each parameter. They are all within a negligible window, so I would like to preserve perhaps just the first one for each sampling ID. Such as salinity at 11:37 and pH at 11:38 with the output row just showing 11:37 for the sampling ID.

Any advice would be much appreciated because I have already been banging my head against the wall looking for an efficient way to analyze this massive dataset organized in a way far from my preferred format for too long.

Answer (score 1):

With `spread` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

spread(df, Parameter, Result)
```

Returns:

```
  ID Location  DO  pH Salinity
1 a1       x1 7.3 8.1     32.7
2 b2       x2 7.6 8.3     31.2
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. This is a good start, but still pretty far from looking like what I am hoping for. I have been looking into tidyr and dplyr, but they are both new to me. I will start trying to play with spread more, but basically this is solving my problem of getting the parameter names as column names and filling in some results, but not combining within the IDs. This code is somehow choosing to combine some, but mainly it is a lot of NAs throughout all the blank spaces with still a bunch of rows per site visit. Do you know how to select by the ID to combine these well?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example of your dataset using `dput` and your desired output (like you have already done but including the NA problem you are facing).